# Use of optInTimePeriod in talib

Tags: ta-lib

I  have a question related to talib, in multiple functions we use a parameter called `optInTimePeriod`. What is the use of this parameter? How I should use it? 
Following is the documentation of `MAX` function.

**MAX - Highest value over a specified period**

```
talib.MAX(params)
```

*Input parameters:*

- inReal - array of floats
- startIdx - start index for input data
- endIdx - end index for input data
- optInTimePeriod

*Returns:*

- array of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better check out it's C++ API documentation regarding function params: https://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html#Technical%20Analysis%20Functions

As for TA_MAX - time period is a size of moving data window in which you are looking for max values. For ex, if your array is [0,1,2,3,4,5] and optInTimePeriod is 1 you'll get a result array [0,1,2,3,4,5]. For optInTimePeriod equal 3 you'll get only [2,3,4,5]. If you just want a max value across all data your optInTimePeriod should be more or equal to size of data array.
The default value for optInTimePeriod in TA_MAX is 30. It may be different for other functions.